# No implicit conversion between null and T

Tags: c#, sql, generics, null, dapper

Parameter 'T value' can be null, problem is when I attempt to run the dapper query where T value is null (and my table does allow nulls) I get this error

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

So in my anonymous object I am checking if T value is null or not but the issue I am getting is this:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'T'

Problem with line:

```
value = value.Equals(default(T)) ? null : value,
```

I want to be able to update value as NULL into the table if T is null otherwise the value which can be of type int, string etc.
Anyone can help to get this working  please?
Thanks

Code:

```
   public async Task UpdateAsync<T>(string field, T value, int id)
    {
        using (var sql = dbConnectionFactory())
        {
            await sql.ExecuteAsync($@"
                UPDATE {TABLE} SET {field} = @value WHERE Id = @id",
                new
                {
                    value = value.Equals(default(T)) ? null : value,
                    id
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: T could be a struct so null is not a valid default value. Use `default(T)` instead.

Comment: Please tell us **what you are trying to achieve** by using `value = value.Equals(default(T)) ? null : value,`.

Comment: If T is a struct, it can't be `null`. If it's a class, it's default is `null`.

Comment: Also, beware of bobby tables

Comment: Please show us at least three examples of how you plan to call `UpdateAsync`. Please ensure you show us examples where `T` is of type string, int and nullable int (at the very least).

Answer (score 1):

You should tell to compiller that 'T' can be null

```
public async Task UpdateAsync<T>(string field, T value, int id) where T: class
```

Comment: That would make the condition redundant - the `default(T)` when `T` is a class is `null`.